# Why does my async/await example not work?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have trouble understanding the whole concept of `async/await` and have spent hours reading the documentation and trying to get an example to work. But I still do not understand why this tiny example does not work.

The result I want is for `document.body.innerHTML` to contain the text "123", since `doFirst()` should finish running before `doSomething()` finishes.

But I always get "132", as if I haven’t used async/await at all. What am I doing wrong?

```js
async function doFirst() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "1";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "2";
  }, 500);
}

async function doSomething()
{
  await doFirst();
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "3";
}

doSomething();
```

Sorry for posting this again, last time I posted this question it was marked as a duplicate. So this time I want to clarify that I’m not looking for any answers that show me *how* to do it properly but also for explanations on *why* my code does not work.

Comment: `setTimeout` is callback-based, not Promise-based. You need to convert it to a Promise so you can return it from `doFirst`, so that the `doSomething` can consume it as a Promise

Comment: @CertainPerformance, this user is looking for an explanation, not a "fix this code".  This is not a duplicate of that question and it doesn't help them much.  This should be re-opened.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the `doFirst()` returns a promise that is resolved before the timer runs out. Contrary to your expectations, `setTimeout` does not pause script execution.

In order to ensure that `doFirst()` resolves *after* the timer runs out, you will need to wrap the entire function inside a `Promise` object. The timer will call the `resolve()` method once it runs out, as such:

```js
function doFirst() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "1";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "2";
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}

async function doSomething()
{
  await doFirst();
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "3";
}

doSomething();
```

If you want to avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), an cleaner way is to simply create a utility function that resolves a promise after a setTimeout, then you can await on the promise returned from that function to be resolved before printing "2" into the DOM:

```js
// Utility function that resovles a promise after a given duration
function sleep(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

async function doFirst() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "1";
  await sleep(500);
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "2";
}

async function doSomething()
{
  await doFirst();
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "3";
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at below code:

```
async function doFirst() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "1";
  return myAsyncFunc(500)
}

function myAsyncFunc(delay) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "2"
            resolve();
        }, delay));
}

async function doSomething()
{
  await doFirst();
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "3";
}
```

> What are you doing wrong ?

You are not returning a promise in `doFirst()` , so the operation is not asynchronus (in short, your code `doSomething()` does not wait for `doFirst()` to finish up and move to line `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "3";`)

Note:

1. How `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "1";` is run immediately and the `myAsyncFunc` is returned (which basically returns a `Promise`).
2. After 500ms , `setTimeout` executes and hence `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "2"` is run.  After that, the next line `return resolve()` is returned , which marks the `Promise` to be completed.
3. The `await` is over as soon as `resolve` is returned and so the "3" is added

Comment: “You are now returning a promise in `doFirst()`[…]” – I think you mean “not” instead of “now” though that’s not true. `doFirst` does indeed return a promise, just one that does not wait for the timeout in order to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misconception about what the `async` keyword does. It does not magically change the function to be asynchronous, despite its name. It only does the following two things:

1. Allow `await` to be used inside the function body.
2. Ensure the function returns a Promise.

But only when those two are used in concert is it actually useful. An async function without `await` in its body does not need to be async at all.

Your example function `doFirst` does not use `await`, so it’s essentially equivalent to the following:

```js
function doFirst() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "1";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "2";
    }, 500);
    return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
```

As you can see, there’s nothing asynchronous about this code. `Promise.resolve` returns a promise that can immediately resolve to the given value. This means using `await doFirst()` in `doSomething` will not actually await anything as the promise is already resolved.

What you want for `doFirst` to do is return a promise that won’t resolve until the `setTimeout` callback has executed. Unfortunately `setTimeout` does not return a promise so you’ll need to create one manually:

```js
function doFirst() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "1";
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "2";
            resolve();
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

You may notice that you don’t need the `async` keyword here. That’s because the function does not use `await` and already returns a promise. `doSomething` will still be able to use `await doFirst()` because `await` works with any promise, not just when calling async functions.